# How to set flex-shrink : 0 in Polymer

Tags: polymer, flexbox

Currently, my class has the following code. I want to make `flex-shrink: 0`; How to do it?
[Documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout) says `--layout-flex-auto : Sets flex flex-basis to auto and flex-grow and flex-shrink to 1.`

```
@apply(--layout-flex);
@apply(--layout-vertical);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS rules that appear later override earlier rules if both have the same [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

To override the `flex-shrink` value from the mixin, just place your `flex-shrink` setting **after** the mixin:

```
<style>
  .container {
    @apply(--layout-flex);
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
</style>
```